# Coloured theorem with optional argument

Tags: color, theorems

Have written the command `teora` that prints with the colour defined in `\pigm`.  Could `\teora` be changed to accept the colour as an optional parameter?  `\newtheorem` already accepts an optional theorem naming parameter, and most likley that I cannot have multiple optional parameters.  But I am not sure.

```
\newcommand{\pigm}{Green}
\newtheorem{teora}{\color{\pigm}Theorem}[section]
```

How can a user change the colour for `\pigm` so that one can have a different colour when calling `\teora`.

```
\begin{teora}[Pythagorean theorem]
  To prove it by contradiction try and assume that the statement is
  false, proceed from there and at some point you will arrive to a
  contradiction.
\end{teora}
```

There is the possibility of doing `\begin{teora}[\color{Green}Pythagorean theorem]` but this only changes the name, with the theorem numbering keeping with the old colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use an optional argument in parentheses, so as not to conflict with the standard optional argument for the name.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newcommand{\teoracolor}{}% initialize
\newtheorem{teorainner}{\color{\teoracolor}Theorem}[section]
\NewDocumentEnvironment{teora}{D(){teora}}
 {\renewcommand{\teoracolor}{#1}\teorainner}
 {\endteorainner}

\colorlet{teora}{green!80!blue}

\begin{document}

\section{Title}

\begin{teora}
This theorem is green, with no name.
\end{teora}

\begin{teora}[Name]
This theorem is green, with a name.
\end{teora}

\begin{teora}(red!80)
This theorem is red, with no name.
\end{teora}

\begin{teora}(red!80)[Name]
This theorem is red, with a name.
\end{teora}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could I build it without `\usepackage{amsthm}`?

Comment: With `\newcommand{\pigm}{Green}` in a style file, is there a way for users to change the value of `\pigm` to another taken from `xcolor`?

Comment: `\NewDocumentEnvironment` is a latex built-in that is not associated with `amsthm`, right?

Comment: @konmi I always use `amsthm` because it adds punctuation, but is not necessary for the job. You can use `\pigm` instead of the `teora` color, if you so prefer, but is it a sensible name?

Comment: I have no problem using the colour you defined.

Comment: I have seen that your solution also works with colour names, thus `\begin{teora}(Sienna)[Name]`

Comment: @konmi Yes, of course. The optional argument can be anything that ultimately expands to a color name specification.

Comment: Very Very Good @egreg

Comment: What is the meaning of `D()` used in `\NewDocumentEnvironment`?

Comment: @konmi It specifies an optional argument enclosed in parentheses; the default value follows. See `texdoc usrguide3`

Comment: What are the particular features that makes  `\NewDocumentEnvironment`  a better choice, than using  `\newenvironment` or  `\newtheorem`?

Comment: @konmi Much more flexible.